Solving difficult Gent model equations for dependency
To preface, I'm very new to mathematica, and it's hard for me to figure out how to continue with this.
This is a current code:
w[x_, y_] = -(1/2) \[Mu] Jm Log[1 - (x^2 + y^2 + 1/(x*y)^2 - 3)/Jm]
w1[x_, y_] = D[w[x, y], x]
w2[x_, y_] = D[w[x, y], y]
pressure = w1[x, y]/(x*y)
axialforce = -((x^2 * pressure)/2) + w2[x, y]
soln = Solve[Numerator[Simplify[axialforce]] == 0, y]
yy = y /. soln[[4]][[1]]
Plot[pressure /. y -> yy /. \[Mu] -> 1 /. Jm -> 97.5, {x, 1, 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"lambda1", "Pressure"}]

eqn1 = w2[r0, z0] - 1/2  pressure  r0^2;
eqn2 = w[r0, z0] - z0  w2[r0, z0] - w[x, yy] + yy  w2[x, yy];
aaa = Numerator[Simplify[eqn1]] /. Jm -> 97.5 /. \[Mu] -> 1  /. y -> yy

For variables, W denotes a Gent Model, mu and Jm will be constants, yy was solved - which acts as lambda 2. aaa is just a placeholder for now and nothing very relevant as I was messing with the code to find relationships between r0 and z0 or any hints to move on. If it's needed, I can use a value of lambda 1 (so, x) into yy and that way for any value of lambda 1 I get a lambda 2.
So, the background is I am currently working on a project in area of localised bulging in rubber tubes that asks us to solve eqn1 and eqn2 for dependence of r0 and z0 on lambda 1 (x in the code). Previous step was to solve lambda 2 (named y at the start) for each value of lambda 1 - I managed to get there using relationship between lambda 1 and pressure so then I could use various values of x to find y.
I basically am asking for how to move on with the code in order to try and get closer to the solution and therefore to plot a dependence of r0 and z0 on lambda 1 - I've tried subbing in eqn1 into eqn2 based on properties of w2 when both equations equal 0, but that didn't help. I've used y->1 and x->1 in the aa line in order to find more relationships, but it also didn't produce much. At the minute, eqn1 contains a lot of x,y,r0,z0's -> of course y can be subbed as yy (solved lambda 2) and then that way I can have just x,r0 and z0 -> exactly what I need.
The problem with that is though, that I have no idea how to move on from that to show the latter 2 variables's dependence on x (i.e. lambda 1)

It is hard to figure out what you want here. Perhaps editing the text and removing references of lamba, or editing the code and using lambda instead of x.
eqn1 and eq2 aren't equations, so it is not clear what you mean by solving them for r0 and z0.
Clarifying your question is likely to get a better and quicker answer.

What I mean is, in order for mathematica to understand - I assigned x as lambda 1 and y as lambda 2, that's how they're noted in my equation derivations.
Then, I have went about working out a way to solve y for given x using the pressure relation with x (and also to achieve a working graph to identify the point of bulging)
Now I am stuck with trying to find the dependence of r0 and z0 on x, which are the final 2 lines where I want to solve those equations to determine my final bulging equations further - and I don't know what is the next step
Hopefully this somehow clarifies it better!

https://prnt.sc/yqo4hPRsPRK3 - Currently this is what I have, when I substitute values of x, yy. Jm and mu into the last two equations, I need to figure out where to go from here and if there's a way to obtain the dependancy without having to state x and yy values

I see the left hand sides (perhaps) of equations, but not the right and sides. An equation look like this:  a x == b y.  I'm not sure but it sounds like you want to do something like this: Solve[{eq1,eq2}, {r0,z0}], but eq1 and eq1 need to be equations.

That Solve is exactly what I am trying to compute, would I need to change eqn1 & 2 to be a == to begin with and then have "=0" at the end? (they're both equal to 0)
Also is it allowed to then use Simplify function on these with values input using /. so then solving process is quicker?

Yes, then you want Solve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0}, {r0, z0}].  It will be a complicated expression.  You could do sol = Solve[eqn1 = 0, zo] then pick one of the five solutions you want and then: Solve[eqn2/.sol[[whichOne]]= 0, zo] to get a somewhat less complicated solution, but less general.

I'm not optimistic that an analytical solution can be found given this mix or algebraic and transcendental uses of the variables.

I have tried eqn1 = w2[r0, z0] - 1/2 *pressure *r0^2 == 0; eqn2 = w[r0, z0] - z0  w2[r0, z0] - w[x, yy] + yy  w2[x, yy] == 0; eqn1sub =   Simplify[eqn1 /. y -> yy /. Jm -> 97.5 /. \[Mu] -> 1  /. x -> 1.2] eqn2sub =   Simplify[eqn2 /. y -> yy /. Jm -> 97.5 /. \[Mu] -> 1  /. x -> 1.2] Solve[{eqn1sub == 0, eqn2sub == 0}, {r0, z0}]
It doesn't yield a solution because Solve refuses to work, maybe I need to go back and state eq1 and eq2 explicitly?

It is likely as  Daniel Lichtblau says: a closed form solution may not be obtainable.  In such cases, then you usually resort to numeric methods, or find a way to approximate behavior by using some suitable  approximation or expansion.
